# $\forall x\notin B(a,r)$ , Prove $x$ is exterior point to $B(a,r)$

Tags: general-topology

I'm confused how to prove this thing. I found radius that will fit my requirements but I'm not sure I'm allowed to do that.
**My try :**
let $x_0 \notin B(a,r) \longrightarrow x_0\in B(a,r)^c \longrightarrow ||x_0-a|| > r$ (I know it supposed to be $\ge$ but in this case it can only be $>$)
So I need to prove that $\exists R>0$ such that $B(x_0,R)\subset B(a,r)^c$

I will set a new radius to be $$R=\frac {||x_0-a||-r}{2}>0$$
(Took the distance between $x_0$ to the edge of $B(a,r)^c$ and divided by $2$ to make sure the new Radius $R$ won't reach the ball.)

Can I say the new ball $B(x_0,R)\subset B(a,r)^c$ because the radius is small enough or I need somehow to prove it ?
(here I got stuck and couldn't prove the subset property)
Can I assume the radius is small enough to make sure there is no point in $B(a,r)$ or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your definition of ball of radius $r$ and center $a$ does the inequality is strict or not, id est does $x\in B(a,r)$ iff $ |x-a|<r$ or $|x-a|\leq r$ ? (usually the inequality is strict), and your point follows directly from the definition

Comment: As stated, the conjecture is wrong,at least in Euclidean and other real normed spaces… If $\|x_0-a\|=r$ (which is allowed) no such $R$ can be found (your suggested formula gives $R=0$, ouch !)

Comment: The definition is $|x-a|<r$ , I forgot to mention that $|x_0-a|$ is not $\ge r$ but actually only $>r$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I prove $B(x_0,R)\subset B(a,r)^c$, then your proof ends.

**My try :**

I'll prove $B(x_0,R)\cap B(a,r)=\emptyset$.

If $y \in B(x_0,R)\cap B(a,r)$, then $\|x_0-y\|<R,\|y-a\|<r$.

$\|x_0-a\|=r+2R>r+R$, and using triangle inequality, $\|x_0-a\|\le\|x_0-y\|+\|y-a\|<R+r$.

These two makes contradiction, so for all $y$, $y \notin B(x_0,R)\cap B(a,r)$.

So  $B(x_0,R)\cap B(a,r)=\emptyset$. The proof ends.

Comment: Interesting approach , So you proved there is no intersection and since $x_0 \notin B(a,r)$   this means $B(x_0,R)$ is entirely in the complement of $B(a,r)$...  Great work ! :)

Comment: And what if $\|x_0-a\|=r$?